# Regex pattern for //;\n2;3;4

Tags: javascript, java, regex

I am trying to find a regex which supports a pattern like below:

1. String starts with //
2. String has a delimiter after //; (suppose ; is the delimiter)
3. String has \n after demiliter (//;\n)
4. Finally String contains any number of digits with that delimiter (//;\n2;3;4;5)

I tried `^//\\D+\\n.*$` but it doesn't work.

Comment: java or javascript? have you made any attempt of this yourself?

Comment: I am trying in Java. I tried ^//\\D+\\n.*$ but it doesn't work. Yeah delimiter can change. Even if we get to match pattern till \n then also my work is done!

Answer (score -1):

Sample: `//;\n2;3;4;5`

Answer: `[/]{2}[;]\\[n](\d[;]){1,999}\d`

This will allow further combinations of a decimal followed by ;
\d is added at the end in the case a semicolon is not added judging by your sample

Answer (score -1):

Okay based on your additional comment this could work. It's very messy but it may just get the job done.

```
var string = "//;\n2;3;4;5";

console.log(
  
  string.replace(/[^0-9,.]+/g," ").trim().split(" ").map(function(x){return parseInt(x, 10);}).reduce(function(a, b){return a + b;}, 0)

);
```

Console log results in 14

Comment: Basically there is a string which starts with // followed by a delimiter and then in new line, there are any number of numbers seperated by that delimiter. I have to add these numbers. Hence, I need a regex to first find the string is valid and then retrieve the numbers,